# Showing a Wikipedia article's changes as Git commits

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, git, wikipedia

I created a small-ish NodeJS script which takes as argument the name of a Wikipedia article (and optionally a Wikipedia edition, "en" is default) and creates a Git repository with each change made to the Wikipedia article being represented with a commit.

Here are the code rules that I tried to follow:

- I attempted to structure the code so that it looks as much as possible like a basic binding between the Wikipedia API and the nodegit library
- I'm not very familiar with promises, but I tried to use them when possible
- I used `argparse` to provide a good user experience with parameters.

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/bperel/wiki-as-git) as well if there's a need for details about dependencies.

I would be interested to have feedback about:

- Is the code structured well enough for a developer to understand what it's doing? In particular, is there too much code complexity (indentation
- Am I using too many dependencies? Not enough?

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var pjson = require('./package.json');

var path = require('path');
var nodegit = require('nodegit');
var promisify = require('promisify-node');
var fse = promisify(require('fs-extra'));
var https = require("https");
var moment = require("moment");
var winston = require("winston");

var ArgumentParser = require("argparse").ArgumentParser;
var argparser = new ArgumentParser({
  description: pjson.name,
  version: pjson.version
});

argparser.addArgument('--language',{ nargs: 1, defaultValue: 'en', help: 'The Wikipedia language version to use (ex: en, fr, etc.)' });
argparser.addArgument('-vvv',{ nargs: 0, help: 'Verbose log' });
argparser.addArgument('articleName');

var args = argparser.parseArgs();

var defaults = {
    commitMessageLength: 100,
    logLevel: 'info'
};

var log = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: args.vvv ? 'verbose': defaults.logLevel })
    ]
});

var fileName = args.articleName + '.wiki';

var apiRoot = 'https://' + args.language + '.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';
var url = apiRoot + '?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=' + encodeURIComponent(args.articleName) + '&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment%7Ccontent&rvlimit=max';

var repoDir = './' + args.language + '.wikipedia.org/' + args.articleName;
var repoPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), repoDir);

var repo;
var revisions;
var currentRevisionId;

function createCommitForCurrentRevision() {
    var revision = revisions[currentRevisionId];
    var fileContent = revision['*'];
    var message = revision.comment.substr(0, defaults.commitMessageLength);
    var author = revision.user;
    var date = revision.timestamp;

    log.verbose("Creating commit for revision " + currentRevisionId);

    promisify(fse.writeFile(path.join(repo.workdir(), fileName), fileContent))
        .then(function(){
            return repo.refreshIndex();
        })
        .then(function(idx) {
            index = idx;
        })
        .then(function() {
            return index.addByPath(fileName);
        })
        .then(function() {
            return index.write();
        })
        .then(function() {
            var timestamp = moment(date, moment.ISO_8601);
            var authorSignature = nodegit.Signature.create(author, author + "@test.com", timestamp.unix(), 60);

            if (currentRevisionId === 0) { // First commit
                return index.writeTree()
                    .then(function(oid) {
                        return repo.createCommit("HEAD", authorSignature, authorSignature, message, oid, []);
                    })
            }
            else {
                return index.writeTree()
                    .then(function(oidResult) {
                         oid = oidResult;
                         return nodegit.Reference.nameToId(repo, "HEAD");
                    })
                    .then(function(head) {
                        return repo.getCommit(head);
                    })
                    .then(function(parent) {
                        return repo.createCommit("HEAD", authorSignature, authorSignature, message, oid, [parent]);
                    })
            }
        })
        .done(function(commitId) {
            log.verbose("New commit created: ", commitId);
            currentRevisionId++;
            if (currentRevisionId < revisions.length) {
                createCommitForCurrentRevision();
            }
            else {
                log.info('The article\'s revision history was saved in ' + repoPath);
            }
        });
}

log.verbose("Cleaning previous local repository if existing");
fse.removeSync(repoPath);

promisify(fse.ensureDir)(repoPath)
    .then(function() {
        return nodegit.Repository.init(repoPath, 0);
    })
    .then(function(repoCreated) {
        log.verbose("Created empty repository " + repoCreated);
        repo = repoCreated;
        log.verbose("Retrieving article history from " + url);
        https.get(url, function(res){
            var body = '';

            res.on('data', function(chunk){
                body += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', function(){
                log.verbose("Article history has been retrieved");
                var response = JSON.parse(body);
                Object.keys(response.query.pages).forEach(function(pageId) {
                    var page = response.query.pages[pageId];
                    revisions = page.revisions.reverse();

                    currentRevisionId = 0;
                    createCommitForCurrentRevision();
                });
            });
        })
     });
```